# Is there a way to use Autocomplete without JQuery UI

Tags: jquery, autocomplete

Is there a way to use autocomplete without JQuery  UI cause JQuery UI's footprint is too large (including its CSS) ?

or is there any alternative plugin or something, I googled this a lot but didn't find any.

Comment: There're number of jQuery autocomplete plugins that do not require jQuery UI and it's CSS. Probably one of the most used: http://bassistance.de/jquery-plugins/jquery-plugin-autocomplete/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can build your own that does not depend on JQuery UI, its a very simple idea of trigger field onchange(), issue an AJAX call to get result that matches what you typed so far, and populate some field with a div or drop down below or near it. And on select of the div or drop down, you populate your trigger field with selected value.

I know that Jquery Autosuggest does not use JQuery UI but does require JQuery.

Comment: I can build it on my own but I'll have to do a lot of things like 
1-highlighting text , 2-handling keyboard keys -> Up / down , enter ...etc a lot of things to handle

Comment: Yes, thats why I also give you a suggested plugin, and here is another one: http://www.devbridge.com/projects/autocomplete/jquery/

Comment: Autosuggest is exactly what I'm looking for :D

Answer (score 1):

Just found this facebook-style jQuery plugin that is currently maintained and doesn't require the bloat of jQuery UI

https://github.com/loopj/jquery-tokeninput

Comment: downvoted because the OP explicitly asked for an answer that does not use jQuery.

Answer (score 1):

Refer below snippet for autocomplete without using jQuery. This is plain html5 with datalist tag works on all modern browsers.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<!--your stuff-->
</head>
<body>
<!--your stuff-->
<input type="text" id="txtAutoComplete" list="languageList"/><!--your input textbox-->
<datalist id="languageList">
<option value="HTML" />
<option value="CSS" />
<option value="JavaScript" />
<option value="SQL" />
<option value="PHP" />
<option value="jQuery" />
<option value="Bootstrap" />
<option value="Angular" />
<option value="ASP.NET" />
<option value="XML" />
</datalist>
</body>
</html>
```

If need help related to implement this, refer this [link](http://www.cheezycode.com/2015/09/create-auto-complete-dropdown-using.html)

Answer (score 0):

No need to include JQuery or any other third party library.

`IP_autoComplete` function will automatically concatinate field value to URL (1st parameter). For example textbox has value `neeraj` then `arrjson.php?Name=neeraj` will be triggered.

You can use IP_autocomplete function for static value as well. Just add # sign once at starting in your string (comma sepreated). E.g: "#val1,val2,val3"

arrjson.php should return json encoded string.

HTML:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://services.iperfect.net/js/IP_generalLib.js">
```

Body

```
<input type="text" name="testautocomplete" id="testautocomplete" onkeypress="IP_autoComplete('arrjson.php?Name=',this.id,event)">
```

Or simply you can give static:

```
<input type="text" name="testneeraj" id="testneeraj" onkeyup="IP_autoComplete('#sachin bhalake,ishwar agam,mohsin khan,neeraj dhekale,sheetal dhekale,ajay bhalake',this.id,event)">
```